# Trying to style pressed/selected style on MultiButton in Codename One results in Stack Overflow Error

Tags: css, codenameone

I just wanted to give a feedback to the user when they press a `MultiButton` that has been styled in CSS.

The `MultiButton` is used like this :

```
 String newStyleName = "NewText";
    Style newStyle = new Label("g", newStyleName).getUnselectedStyle();
    String newSubStyleName = "NewSubText";
    String newIconStyleName = "NewIcon";

MultiButton nameButton = new MultiButton("Name");
    nameButton.setTextLine2("Give a name");
    nameButton.setIcon(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_TEXT_FIELDS, newStyle));
    nameButton.setIconUIID(newIconStyleName);
    nameButton.setUIIDLine1(newStyleName);
    nameButton.setUIIDLine2(newSubStyleName);
    this.add(nameButton);
```

And styled like this :

```
NewText {
color: #000000; 
background-color: #e2f1f8;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 2mm;
padding-right: 2mm;
padding-top: 1mm;
padding-bottom: 1px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-family: "native:MainLight"; 
font-size: 4.2mm; 
}

NewSubText {
cn1-derive: NewText;
padding-top: 0mm;
padding-bottom: 1mm;
margin-bottom: 0mm;
color: #b0bec5;
font-size: 3.5mm;
}

NewIcon {
cn1-derive: NewText;
padding-top: 1mm;
padding-bottom: 1mm;
padding-left: 2mm;
padding-right: 2mm; 
background-color: #e2f1f8;
}
```

To achieve my goal to give feedback to the user, I have added :

```
NewText.pressed {
cn1-derive: NewText;
background-color: #808d94;
}

NewText.selected {
cn1-derive: "NewText.pressed";   
}
```

But this leads to an error in the simulator :

```
Error creating style NewText. selected: false prefix: press#[EDT] 0:1:2,42 - Error creating style NewText. selected: false prefix: press#

java.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.codename1.io.Log.createWriter(Log.java:367)
at com.codename1.io.Log.getWriter(Log.java:384)
at com.codename1.io.Log.print(Log.java:348)
at com.codename1.io.Log.p(Log.java:284)
at com.codename1.io.Log.p(Log.java:274)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getComponentStyleImpl(UIManager.java:356)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.createStyle(UIManager.java:1364)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.getComponentStyleImpl(UIManager.java:349)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.createStyle(UIManager.java:1364)
```

and if I keep pressing on the button it finally colors in the pressed background color.

By the way if I only define the selected style (no pressed style) it does not compile :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.codename1.ui.css.CSSTheme$Element.getFlattenedStyle(CSSTheme.java:2650)
```

So it looks like there is a cyclic dependency problem between styles causing this stack overflow error but I cannot see where : `NewText` selector style is fully defined.

What does this `false prefix press#` mean, and how can I do to remove this error ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you had time to try this small helper library https://github.com/diamonddevgroup/cn1-helper, it has been so useful to me and easier to use than CSS. It allows you to do most of your styling in code on a single line.

Comment: Thanks  Diamond for bringing this helper to my knowledge. I would give it a try if I am stuck with the css way which I personally prefer so far.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is a cyclic inheritance dependency between components which is why the derive style attribute is so tricky. It's harder to see what goes on because sometimes inheritance is defined in the base theme e.g. `MultiButton` might derive from `Button`.

Comment: Thanks Shai. So the easiest solution would be to copy paste the style to avoid the inheritance in this case. I'll give it a try and keep you posted.